# MySQL - Convert many small querys to big one

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got the following code:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT views FROM restaurant_views 
WHERE (restaurant_id=:rest_id) AND (date=:date) LIMIT 1");

for($i = 11; $i > -1; $i--){
    $query->bindParam(":rest_id", $_SESSION['restaurant_id']);
    $query->bindParam(":date", date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-{$i} days")));
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $i . ' - ' . $row['views'].'<br>';                     
}
```

The output is this:

1. 5
2. 12
3. 30
4. 0
5. 6
6. 8
7. 5
8. 5
9. 0
10. 0
11. 0
12. 5

This is working as it should, but I want to remove this loop and be able to retrieve the *views* for all the days at once. Keep in mind that if a restaurant does not have any views for one day, then the row does not exist. *(The row is created on the first view)* so the output won't be 12 rows. **It must be 12 rows, very important!**

Comment: What does the last bit mean? "Keep in mind that if a restaurant does not have any views for one day, then the row does not exist. (The row is created on the first view) so the output won't be 12 rows. It must be 12 rows, very important!"

Comment: I save the date and the amount of views in the database in the restaurant_views table. If there are no views for that day, there is no row for it. (No row --> no views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want twelve rows, then add a "table" in the query to get twelve rows:

```
SELECT n.n, rv.views
FROM (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all 
      select 8 union all select 9  union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
     ) n left join
     restaurant_views rv
     on rv.date = date_sub(curdate(), interval n.n day) and
        restaurant_id=:rest_id ;
```

I'm not sure what the `limit` clause is doing.  Does one restaurant in `restaurant_views` have more than one row on any given day?

Comment: Works! The only thing I had to change was from date_sub to date_add. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Tompa . . . Or `date_sub()` with a positive value.  To many negatives before my last edit.